# Computing P-value

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, sampling

In a book, from a sample they derived *Mantel-Haenszel chi-square statistic*
$$\chi_1^2=1.41$$

And it is written that :

**this $\chi_1^2=1.41$ is associated with a one-sided P-value between $0.10$ and $0.15$**

I tried to compute  the P-value . But My result is not $0.10$ and $0.15$. So i doubt whether my procedure to compute the P-value is appropriate.

$$(1/2)pr(\chi_1^2\ge 1.41|H_0)\approx pr(Z>\sqrt(1.41)|H_0)=0.1175282$$

- **How can i calculate the P-value and why is it one-sided?Is that for $\chi^2$ is a one-tail test?**

Comment: "**between** 0.10 and 0.15".

Comment: @StefanHansen Why have they given the range of P-value (`between` .10 and .15) instead of giving one value like $0.1175282$?

Comment: They have probably used a table rather than calculating the p-value explicitly.

Comment: @StefanHansen Now it's clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that a chi-squared random variable with one degree of freedom obtains a value higher than $1.41$ is $.235$,

$$P\left(\chi^2_1\geq 1.41\right) = 0.235$$

So what the authors say is valid only if they are conducting a two-tailed test, and so this probability is split in two (which leads to $0.1175$). And in any case, the phrasing they use is confusing.

Comment: Isn't $pr(\chi_1^2\ge 1.41|H_0)$ a one tail test since it only considers upper region as critical region? Also isn't $pr(Z>\sqrt(1.41)|H_0)$ a one tail test ? Also the author of the book phrases it as `one tail test`. I apology.I am not understanding the point of saying it a `two-tailed test` in your answer.

Comment: If it is a one-tailed test then all the probability mass is in one piece, so it is $0.235$, and so the"value between $0.10$ and $0.15$" or $0.1175$ are simply wrong. So most probably the authors have in mind a two-tailed test, and they confusingly talk about a $one-sided p-value$, meaning the p-value in the one of the two tails.